# Mostrar datos cargados a un array en forma de lista

Tags: javascript, html, array

Quiero mediante un campo de texto y un boton HTML ir cargando y mostrando el ingreso de nombres en forma de lista. No puedo lograr que se muestre el nombre ingresado al momento de presionar el boton. No me da ningun error simplemente no lo muestra y nose que esta incorrecto.

Mi codigo HTML es este:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="Ejercicio.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Ejercicio </h2>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="txt">
        <input type="button" value="Ingresar y Mostrar" id="btn">
    </form>
    <ul id="resultado"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Y mi codigo javascript es este :

```
function inicio(){
    document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", ejercicio);
}

let alias = [];
function ejercicio(){
    let usuario = document.querySelector("#txt").value;
    alias.push(usuario);
    document.querySelector("#resultado").innerHTML = "";
    for(let elem of alias){
        document.querySelector("#resultado").innerHTML += "<li>"+elem+"</li>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola hay varios errores en tu script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola tienes varios errores, el principal es que no se va a ejecutar jamás tu JavaScript por que esta dentro de una funcion `inicio` que nunca invocas... segundo error es el código adicional que no necesitas, el cual he eliminado ... te dejo el ejemplo ya ejecutándose:

```js
function inicio(){
    document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", ejercicio);
}

function ejercicio(){
    let usuario = document.querySelector("#txt").value;
    document.querySelector("#resultado").innerHTML += "<li>"+usuario+"</li>";
}

inicio();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Ejercicio </h2>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="txt">
        <input type="button" value="Ingresar y Mostrar" id="btn">
    </form>
    <ul id="resultado"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```